# Filling Out & Filtering Irregular Time Series Data

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgresql 9.4, I am trying to craft a query on time series log data that logs new values whenever the value updates (not on a schedule).  The log can update anywhere from several times a minute to once a day.

I need the query to accomplish the following:

1. Filter *too much* data by just selecting the first entry for the timestamp range
2. Fill in *sparse* data by using the **last reading** for the log value.  For example, if I am grouping the data by hour and there was an entry at 8am with a log value of 10.  Then the next entry isn't until 11am with a log value of 15, I would want the query to return something like this:

```
Timestamp        | Value
2015-07-01 08:00 | 10 
2015-07-01 09:00 | 10 
2015-07-01 10:00 | 10 
2015-07-01 11:00 | 15
```

I have got a query that accomplishes the first of these goals:

```
with time_range as (
    select hour
    from generate_series('2015-07-01 00:00'::timestamp, '2015-07-02 00:00'::timestamp, '1 hour') as hour
),
ranked_logs as (
    select 
        date_trunc('hour', time_stamp) as log_hour,
        log_val,
        rank() over (partition by date_trunc('hour', time_stamp) order by time_stamp asc)
    from time_series
)
select 
    time_range.hour,
    ranked_logs.log_val
from time_range
left outer join ranked_logs on ranked_logs.log_hour = time_range.hour and ranked_logs.rank = 1;
```

But I can't figure out how to fill in the *nulls* where there is no value.  I tried using the lag() feature of Postgresql's Window functions, but it didn't work when there were multiple nulls in a row.

Here's a SQLFiddle that demonstrates the issue:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f4d13/5/0

Answer (score 1):

your columns are `log_hour` and `first_vlue`

```
with time_range as (
    select hour
    from generate_series('2015-07-01 00:00'::timestamp, '2015-07-02 00:00'::timestamp, '1 hour') as hour
),
ranked_logs as (
    select 
        date_trunc('hour', time_stamp) as log_hour,
        log_val,
        rank() over (partition by date_trunc('hour', time_stamp) order by time_stamp asc)
    from time_series
),
base as (
select 
    time_range.hour lh,
    ranked_logs.log_val
from time_range
left outer join ranked_logs on ranked_logs.log_hour = time_range.hour and ranked_logs.rank = 1)
SELECT
  log_hour, log_val, value_partition, first_value(log_val) over (partition by value_partition order by log_hour)
FROM (
SELECT
    date_trunc('hour', base.lh) as log_hour,
    log_val,
    sum(case when log_val is null then 0 else 1 end) over (order by base.lh) as value_partition
  FROM base) as q
```

---

**UPDATE**

this is what your query return

```
Timestamp        | Value
2015-07-01 01:00 | 10 
2015-07-01 02:00 | null 
2015-07-01 03:00 | null 
2015-07-01 04:00 | 15 
2015-07-01 05:00 | nul 
2015-07-01 06:00 | 19 
2015-07-01 08:00 | 13
```

I want this result set to be split in groups like this

```
2015-07-01 01:00 | 10       
2015-07-01 02:00 | null     
2015-07-01 03:00 | null    

2015-07-01 04:00 | 15     
2015-07-01 05:00 | nul    

2015-07-01 06:00 | 19     

2015-07-01 08:00 | 13
```

and  to assign to every  row in a group the value of first row from that group (done by last select)

In this case, a method for obtaining the grouping is to create a column which holds the number of 
not null values counted until current row and split by this value.  (use of `sum(case)`)

```
value  | sum(case)
| 10   | 1 |   
| null | 1 |    
| null | 1 |   
| 15   | 2 |  <-- new not null, increment 
| nul  | 2 |  
| 19   | 3 |  <-- new not null, increment 
| 13   | 4 |  <-- new not null, increment
```

and now I can partion by `sum(case)`

Comment: Wow, that seem's to work perfectly.  Can you explain what's going on in the subselect (the `sum(case when ...etc)` ?